# Screen resolution problems on Samsung monitor

Tags: graphics, resolution, monitor

I have a monitor Samsung 19' which resolution is 1440x900 (16:10 aspect ratio). When I set it in the recently installed Ubuntu 13.04, the bottom of the screen gets cut out

Trying to change to another resolution in which I would be able to view all the screen, I found that 1280x960 (4:3) worked. The screen looks stretched and low resolution, though.

How do I fix it? Consider in your answer that I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Read the post from the link. Before starting using those commands, use the command "xrandr" that will show "DP1" or "VGA1" or "etc" connected. Use that "etc" instead of that "DP1" from this link. See if it works.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2161010&p=12729210#post12729210

PS: In the begining of this thread is another link that goes to another thread more explicitely. Hope it helps. See ya

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Before you use xrandr, use cvt to generate a Modeline with your desired resolution *and* frequency.  For example...

```
$ cvt 1280 1024 60.09
```

The result will be something like...

```
# 1280x1024 60.03 Hz (CVT) hsync: 63.81 kHz; pclk: 109.25 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.09"  109.25  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

**(2)** Now, this is the new mode you should create using xrandr...

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.09"  109.25  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

**(3)** Then add your new mode using xrandr...

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.09
```

**(4)** Finally, test it...

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024_60.09
```

(Make sure the output display device, such as VGA1, is your correct device as shown in Ubuntu Display Settings).

Comment: Thanks PJ Singh. I have a 24' Samsung T24c550 and using these parameters worked for me: 
$ cvt 1920 1080 60.09
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.09"  173.25  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1121 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.09

Comment: You're welcome!  If you want to make it permanent, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/330293/how-do-i-set-a-monitor-resolution-that-is-not-available-in-the-display-settings/330373#330373