# resolution problem of ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, display-resolution

Dear ubuntu team and users

I installed ubuntu 20.04 Desktop 64 system.
I use DEll PRECISION T5400 workstation.
After installation I have got very low resolution.
I have tried :

1. To change this, increase this resolution from `Display options in Ubuntu` but I found just one resolution `640 X 480`. Nothing more!!!
2. I followed the posts on net of similar problems but I got nothing instead I got more troubles some times.

Details:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [Quadro NVS 290]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6311ESB/6321ESB PCI Express Upstream Port (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: google(T5400) => Chipset Type: Intel 5400 and "NVIDIA Quadro NVS 290" w 256MB DDR2 SDRAM on a plugin card. (https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-precision-t5400-quad-core-intel-xeon-processor-e5410-2-33ghz-2x6m-l2-1333-80gb-hdd-1gb-ram/) - install nVidia drivers?

Comment: See if this works for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/329072/100356. If it does, you can make it permanent by creating an xorg.conf file: https://askubuntu.com/a/330162/100356

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing 3rd party drivers:

1:     Open "System Settings" -> "Additional drivers"

2:    Select "NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version current)" and click "Activate"

3:    Reboot

Comment: unfortunately, I used NVIDIA from additional drivers and when I reboot it gives me black screen with /dv/sda8 :clean .......

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your bios ?

https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/nvidia-linux/32825-nvidia-quadro-nvs-290-and-linux-cannot-make-it-work

Apparently, the bios of this model plays an important role in how the card will be recognized and operated, and therefore, on the functioning of the nvidia drivers. The graphics card being a G86 variant (similar to 8500GT).

Comment: a link is never an answer by itself. What about when the link is gone? If that link has some helpful info it should be posted in the answer. You can have the link as reference but not just the link.

Comment: Yes, you're right despite the fact i'm new to faskUbuntu's using, i should have been smarter! I'm updating my answer right now.