# How do I set a monitor resolution that is not available in the Display Settings dialog?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

I just installed ubuntu 13.04 x64
My resolution is 800x600 and there is no other option.
I tried to install the nvidia driver 313 but still nothing.
I tried doing this
http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/

still no luck,
thank you

Answer (score 20):

### (1) Get Modeline for your desired resolution

Use `cvt`.  Here is an example for 1280x1024 resolution.  Note that the third parameter (frequency) is optional.  If your owner's manual specifies a refresh rate frequency, you may use that as input to `cvt`, or you can just leave it blank to keep things simple.

```
$ cvt 1280 1024 60
```

The output will look something like this.

```
# 1280x1024 60.03 Hz (CVT) hsync: 63.81 kHz; pclk: 109.25 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60"  109.25  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

### (2) Create a new `xrandr` modeline

Use the `Modeline` output from `cvt` to create a new mode for `xrandr`.

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60"  109.25  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

### (3) Determine which display we need to modify

After running the following command, notice that `VGA1` is the currently connected display, in this example,so we will use it in step number 4, below.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024_60.00   59.9 +
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1280x1024_60   60.0* 
DVI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

### (4) Create a new `xrandr` mode

Use the display name from step 3.  Use the mode name from step number 2, but leave out the quotes.

```
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60
```

### (5) Change the screen resolution

Specify the display name and the mode name

```
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024_60
```

### (6) Get the monitor to automatically adjust

If the monitor has an "Auto Adjust" button, press it to automatically center and scale the output.  Otherwise, use the manual buttons on your monitor to do this.

### (7) Create an `xorg.conf` file

If you like the resolution settings, you can make them permanent by specifying this information in an `xorg.conf` file.

Put the `modeline` from step 1 into the `"Monitor"` section.  You may replace `"My Monitor"` with a descriptive name for your monitor, as long as you use the same name in the `"Screen"` section.

Note that the `"Device"` section is used to specify your graphics card/chip and the driver you are using; `Identifier` may be any name you chose, as long as you use the same name in the `"Screen"` section.  But you must use the correct driver name for your graphics card/chip on the `Driver` line.  You can use `$ lshw -c video | grep configuration` to get your graphics driver name.

Although I have not tested this, it may be possible to exclude the `"Device"` section, as long as you also delete the corresponding `Device` line in the `"Screen"` section.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Enter information into the file, save, and exit.  Here is an example using the 1280x1024 modeline from above and an intel graphics driver.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "My Monitor"
    Modeline    "1280x1024_60"  109.25  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024_60"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel"
    Driver      "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    Device      "Intel"
    Defaultdepth 24
    SubSection  "Display"
        Modes   "1280x1024_60"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Default Layout"
    Screen      "Default Screen"
EndSection
```

If something goes wrong, you can boot into recovery mode and edit or delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Finally, you can take a look at [Ubuntu Wiki Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) for more information.

Comment: I'm really surprised that 1920x1080 isn't provided in the defaults..

Comment: **Just a little info:** Usually Ubuntu should be able to detect the right resolution for your monitor. If you desire a resolution higher than what Ubuntu gives you, it may be that your video cable or graphic card is not capable of serving it. E.g. I wanted 2560x1440p but my cable was only able to serve 2048x1152p. Changing `xorg` didn't help,

Comment: This may be out of date.  I do not have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu stopped shipping with an xorg.conf file.  I beleive you can still create one to set your resolution, as long as your hardware supports the resolution you want.  Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there#4663

Comment: @gerrit this is not outdated, you first need to run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` to generate the xorg.conf file.

Comment: My machine used to have the correct resolution, but suddenly changed today. This answer fixed the problem, but why would it have changed?? The only thing I can think of is that my baby had been playing with the TV settings... That shouldn't affect the aspect ratio on my computer right? It certainly shouldn't delete a whole mode...