# I need to set resolution to 1600x900

Tags: graphics, resolution

On **Displays** I only have 1366x768, but I need 1600x900. I've installed the Nvidia drivers, but still nothing. I've tried using the `xrandr --newmode "1600x900"`, but that doesn't work.

How can I set the resolution to 1600x900?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cvt` to figure out what the correct modeline should be.  You may need to specify the correct frequency for you monitor as well.  Also, ensure your graphics card and monitor actually support the resolution you want to use.  See [How do I set a monitor resolution that is not available in the Display Settings dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330293/graphic-card-issu/330373#330373) to see how to use `cvt`. Then, if `xrandr` works, you can add the settings into `~/.xprofile` instead of `xorg.conf`.