# Set a monitor resolution not available in Display Settings?

Tags: display, display-resolution, monitor, xrandr

> I'm attempting to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330293/how-do-i-set-a-monitor-resolution-that-is-not-available-in-the-display-settings) guide.

My display is `1600x900`, however that resolution is not available in the Display Settings dialogue. I tried a few things, and ended up following the linked guide. I entered the following into the terminal:

```
$ cvt 1600 900
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  141 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  55
  Current serial number in output stream:  55

$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1600x900_60.00"

$ xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

My display is, unsurprisingly, not set to `1600x900`. Where have I erred?

*Note that I'm running this in `Virtualbox`, and have never had this issue, on this machine, with Ubuntu or other virtualizations*

Answer (score 1):

Not a clue why, however I was able to solve the issue by simply renaming the mode. This worked:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60hz"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1600x900_60hz"
$ xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1600x900_60hz"
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I wonder if there was an incomplete mode setting somewhere preventing your first attempt 