# Gnome Settings not showing all available Display Resolutions

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, gnome-settings-daemon

**EDIT**:
Now all resolutions are available.
I am not aware of what did I do to change this...

---

Using Ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo Thinkpad P52.

I added custom screen resolution modes with `xrandr`, and made them permanent via `~/.xprofile`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1344x768_60.00"   84.00  1344 1416 1552 1760  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "1344x744_60.00"   80.75  1344 1408 1544 1744  744 747 757 773 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1-1 "1344x768_60.00"
xrandr --addmode eDP-1-1 "1344x744_60.00"
```

Now they show as available in `xrandr -q` (see below),
but they do not show in *Settings* -> *Displays* -> *Resolution*

[image]

Moreover, there are many other available modes, which were not added by me, which do not show in *Settings* either.
I could select my custom modes via command line with, e.g.,

```
$ xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode "1344x744_60.00"
```

but I want to have them available also via menu.

**How can I have at least my custom modes shown in *Settings*?**

**What determines which modes are shown in *Settings*?**

---

**Output of `xrandr -q`**

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93* 
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   1344x768_60.00  59.81  
   1344x744_60.00  59.90  
  1344x768_60.00 (0x2ba) 84.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1344 start 1416 end 1552 total 1760 skew    0 clock  47.73KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.81Hz
  1344x744_60.00 (0x2bb) 80.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1344 start 1408 end 1544 total 1744 skew    0 clock  46.30KHz
        v: height  744 start  747 end  757 total  773           clock  59.90Hz
```

---

**Related**

1. [How do I set a monitor resolution that is not available in the Display Settings dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330293/how-do-i-set-a-monitor-resolution-that-is-not-available-in-the-display-settings)

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/)